# I'm getting an error message in line 11 near deck[i][j]

Tags: arrays, c, pointers

I'm getting the following error message in 9th line of code (deck[i][j] = ...)
invalid operands to binary + (have ‘char *’ and ‘char *’).
How can I fix this?

```
#include <stdio.h>

char* suit[4] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
char* face[13] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", 
"Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

 char* deck[4][13];

void initialiseDeck(){
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 13; ++j)
        deck[i][j] = face[j] + "of" + suit[i];
}

void display(){
for(int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < 13; ++j)
        printf("%17s\n", deck[i][j]);
}

void shuffleDeck(){

int shuffler[52];
for(int i = 0; i < 52; ++i) shuffler[i] = i;

for(int i = 0; i < 52; ++i){

    int ind = i+(rand()%(52-i));

    int deckI = ind/13;
    int deckJ = ind/13;

    swap(deck[i/13][i%13], deck[deckI][deckJ]);
}
}
```

Comment: `face[j] + "of" + suit[i]`  Strings in C cannot be concatenated with `+`. You need to allocate a buffer for the string and then use a string function like `snprintf` to construct the full string into that buffer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here we go!
So I have added macros to have a more readable code, and also wrote the function `create_card_name`
Here is what is does: it allocates memory for the full name of your card and creates it:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define DECK_SIZE 52
#define SUIT_SIZE 4
#define FACE_SIZE 13


char *suit[SUIT_SIZE] = {"Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs", "Spades"};
char *face[FACE_SIZE] = {"Ace", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine",
                  "Ten", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};

char *deck[SUIT_SIZE][FACE_SIZE];

char * card_name_create(char* face, char* suit)
{
    size_t face_len = strlen(face);
    size_t suit_len = strlen(suit);
    size_t of_len = 4;
    char of[5] = " of ";
    // The size id the size of two strings, than the size of " of " and the '\0'
    char * full_name = malloc(sizeof(char)*(face_len+suit_len+of_len+1));

    for (size_t i = 0; i < face_len; i++)
    {
        full_name[i] = face[i];
    }
    for (size_t i = face_len; i < face_len+of_len; i++)
    {
        full_name[i] = of[i-face_len];
    }
    for (size_t i = face_len+of_len; i < face_len+of_len+suit_len; i++)
    {
        full_name[i] = suit[i - (face_len+of_len) ];
    }
    full_name[face_len+of_len+suit_len] = '\0';
    return full_name;
    
}

void initialiseDeck()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SUIT_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < FACE_SIZE; j++)
        {
            char * c = card_name_create(face[j],suit[i]);
            deck[i][j] = c;
        }   
    }
        
}

void display()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < SUIT_SIZE; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < FACE_SIZE; j++)
        {
            printf("%17s\n", deck[i][j]);
        }
    }        
}
```

Also it would be a great thing to try to not use triple pointers, that is the case of your deck. You can implement all your strings with simple pointers and use `%` to loop through them.